# How to check if any JavaScript event listeners/handlers attached to an element/document?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events

Tried to search online, but does not look like I can formulate search query properly.

How can I, either with jQuery or just javascript list all the handlers or event listeners that are attached to element(s)/document/window or present in DOM?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446892/how-to-find-event-listeners-on-a-dom-node and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7810534/have-any-browsers-implemented-the-dom3-eventlistenerlist/7814692#7814692

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Without jQuery:

if the listeners were added using `elem.addEventListener()` method, it is not easy to list these listeners. You can override the `EventTarget.addEventListener()` method by wrapping it with your own. Then you will have the information, what listeners were registered.

```
var f = EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener; // store original
EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener = function(type, fn, capture) {
  this.f = f;
  this.f(type, fn, capture); // call original method
  alert('Added Event Listener: on' + type);
}
```

Working example you can find at http://jsfiddle.net/tomas1000r/RDW7F/

Comment: nice! correct answer to question.

Answer (score 48):

In jQuery before 1.8, try using `$("#element").data("events")`

**EDIT:**

There is also jQuery extension: [listHandlers](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/debug-jquery-events-with-listhandlers/)

Comment: thank you Laimoncijus, how would you pull that without jquery? may be you could give me link to reading material regarding this subject.

Comment: Seems it is not really possible in current implementation of W3C events model. See: 

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html

(search for "Which event handlers are registered?")

The page there is a little older, so maybe now things got better, can't tell you thins, never tried it myself...

Comment: I have just tried this and it doesn't work.....

Comment: Do you know an non jquery approach? in my unit testing, I always get true for: 
expect(typeof elem[event]).toBe('function');

Comment: not work in jQuery 1.9 and afterwards.

Comment: This doesn't work in newer versions of jQuery. Instead you must now use `$._data($('#element')[0], 'events')` **note:** first paramater must be HTML element, not jQuery

Comment: @Laimoncijus  This seems not working anymore? I am trying it in jasmine test but not working.

Answer (score 32):

When debugging, if you want to just see if there's an event, I recommend using [Visual Event](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event+2) or the *Elements" section of Chrome's Developer Tools: select an element and look for "Event Listeners* on the bottom right.

In your code, if you are using jQuery before version 1.8, you can use:

```
$(selector).data("events")
```

to get the events. As of version 1.8, this is discontinued (see [this bug ticket](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10589)). You can use:

```
$._data(element, "events")
```

but this is not recommended since it is an internal jQuery structure, and could change in future releases.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446892/how-to-find-event-listeners-on-a-dom-node) has some answers which may be useful, but none of them are particularly elegant in the same way that `$(selector).data("events")` was.

Comment: +1 Visual Event is indispensable. I'm frankly surprised this functionality hasn't been subsumed by browsers for their dev tools.

Answer (score 3):

I just discovered visual event 2:

http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event+2

go under the "make it go section" and drag the text link to your bookmark toolbar
go to a page that has events and click on the bookmark

tested in FF Mac

Comment: This is true, currently does not work with delegated events. Ticket is added to hopefully address this in the future:
https://github.com/DataTables/VisualEvent/issues/33