# Accessing an elements event handlers with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I access an elements event handler's with jQuery.

The following link seems to indicate that you could previously access them via $(element).data('events')

[Accessing functions bound to event handlers with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388030/accessing-functions-bound-to-event-handlers-with-jquery)

But this method doesn't seem to work anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(element).data('events')` still works for me.

See here in jQ 1.5.2: http://jsfiddle.net/JAAulde/f82Ky/1/

Comment: Seems like it depends on how it was bound.

Comment: @kennis Can you elaborate? If you mean it depends on whether `live()` or `delegate()` was used as opposed to `bind()` or one of the bind shortcuts, you're quite right. If you mean something else, I need an explanation. (or perhaps you mean jQ may not have been involved at all? in that case, `data()` would not be of help either)

Comment: Sorry. I blame my unreasonable brevity on the fact that it's Friday night. I was in fact referring to live() and delegate().

Comment: Ah, you're right. The events were bound with live, which means they're on the document root. Thanks!