# setting a breakpoint in a native js-method

Tags: javascript, debugging, firebug

I am debuging javascript with firefox+firebug and need to find all calls to .focus() of an HTML-Element.

Ideally i'd like to set a breakpoint in the .focus function.

Comment: I don't know how skilled you are, or if it helps, but you can always fetch the source? [link](http://releases.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/latest/source/) here

Answer (score 0):

You Could

Go to scripts panel on firebug - search for ".focus" or "focus" on the search field and manually add breakpoints . But this becomes cumbersome if you have too many .focus events.

OR

Display all event handlers for an element using the answer in the link below. You can modify this function to check for all .focus event handlers in the page .

[Accessing functions bound to event handlers with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388030/accessing-functions-bound-to-event-handlers-with-jquery)

OR

Use [Visual element](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event) to find out all event handlers on the fly and check out all focus events .

Hope this helps.