# Universal identifier for all jQuery objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging

I need to go really global for some debugging of event handlers I'm looking at [this other stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388030/accessing-functions-bound-to-event-handlers-with-jquery) which is great except that I want to go universal with this

```
// Log ALL handlers for ALL events:
jQuery.each($('#elem').data('events'), function(i, event){
    jQuery.each(event, function(i, handler){
        console.log( handler['handler'].toString() );
    });
});
```

Is there a jQuery identifier for *ALL* jQuery objects?  I would have expected `$(obj)` or `$('*')` but neither does the trick (that or I have another issue).

*Note: the bound event that I'm trying to debug I suspect to be bound via jQuery's `.on()` method at either `body` or `window`.*

**Additional note: is it because I'm binding with `.on()` and it doesn't register events to the `$(document).data('events')` object?**

Comment: If you talking about HTML elements then it is bound to document object and `$(*)` should do the trick.

Comment: Unfortunately I've tried it with no luck, gives me the error `Cannot read length of undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, events / bindings were being suppressed by another jQuery plugin using the [event.stopPropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) method.