# should onclick attribute be explicitly defined so that attr('onclick') show bound click events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following anchor to which I bind a click event using jQuery:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="myanchor">My Anchor</a>
```

**JQuery code:**

```
 function my_listener()
        {

             $('a.myanchor').click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();      
                my_function();
                return false;
           });

        }

$( document ).ready(function() {
    my_listener();
});
```

Now my goal is to be able to see the bound event to the anchor, i.e `my_function()`. I tried using:

```
console.log($('a.myanchor').attr('onclick'));
```

But it is returning `undefined`. How can know that `my_function` is bound to the click event on `a.myanchor`? Does it require explicit `onclick` attribute definition like:

```
<a class="myanchor" onclick="myfun();" >​
```

Thanks for your usual help.

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518421/jquery-find-events-handlers-registered-with-an-object).

Comment: @Regent, thank you, it looks very informative.

Comment: Similar answer for getting event handlers at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388030/accessing-functions-bound-to-event-handlers-with-jquery