# Chrome Userscript (Greasemonkey) - Stop Gmail from sending an email

Tags: google-chrome, gmail, greasemonkey, userscripts

I am writing a Chrome Userscript (Greasemonkey) extension to display a confirmation dialog when the user clicks on Gmail's Send button (in the compose window etc.).

I have manged to attach to the click even of the button and show a dialog when the button is clicked, by using:

```
addEventListener("click", function(e) { ......... }, true);
```

But I cannot stop the email from being sent. I have tried using:

```
e.stopPropagation();
e.preventDefault();
return false;
```

How can I stop Gmail from sending the email?

Comment: I need to do exactly the same! Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that those mentioned by you can prevent default action that is built-in in browser, and stop propagation of event to parent elements in DOM hierarchy. You probably need to get the Gmail's event listener and do something with it - wrap it with your function (so, remove original event listener and bind your function, which displays a dialog and then invoke Gmail's one). Currently, when you only add an event listener, there are two independent event handlers.

Those posts might be useful:
[How to find event listeners on a DOM node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446892/how-to-find-event-listeners-on-a-dom-node)
[How to check if any JavaScript event listeners/handlers attached to an element/document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382994/how-to-check-if-any-javascript-event-listeners-handlers-attached-to-an-element-do)