# select a class in jquery with no event?

Tags: jquery, class

Hi at the minute I am selecting classes like so...

```
$('.colorPick').each(function() {
});
```

Is there a way to select a class name with no event attached, ie in this case

```
.each
```

I have tried,

```
$('.colorPick').(function() {
   });
```

But it doesn't work?

Comment: `.each` is a function, not an event.  If you just want an array of elements, you can do `var list = $('.colorPick');`

Comment: `each` isn't an event though. So what is your end goal?

Comment: I don't understand; what are you trying to do?

Comment: Since you have many elements with the same class i do not think it possible to get the unique  element with just that class you can get the class of the element but you might use somethink like id `var class = $(#id).attr('class');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this can be used to filter out elements with events already attached: [How to check if any JavaScript event listeners/handlers attached to an element/document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382994/how-to-check-if-any-javascript-event-listeners-handlers-attached-to-an-element-d)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean like this?

```
var $colorPics = $('.colorPick');
```

$colorPics will be a jQuery object (which is a container) and will hold the elements.

Comment: Ok will try this, it is because with html5 canvas the only way to select it is with a id, not class!

Answer (score 0):

jQuery objects are just objects that contain lists of elements.  You can use them for many things beyond attaching event handlers.  For example, to iterate through each object that matches a given selector, you can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.colorPick').each(function() {
       // do anything you want here
    });
});
```

Note that I enclosed this in a `document.ready` block so that the code runs after the page loads.   You can see a demo here:  http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/87u2n/.