# Is there a way in javascript to detect if an element has any events attached to it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list of links on the page and sometimes they have events attached to them and sometimes not (they just don't do anything).  I want to say, 'if this element has no event handlers (basically it doesn't do anything), then add a class of disabled to it.  I googled it but didn't find anything for detecting event handlers.  Does anyone know of a way to do something like this??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382994/how-to-check-if-any-javascript-event-listeners-handlers-attached-to-an-element-d

Comment: duplicate? -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515069/jquery-check-if-event-exists-on-element

Comment: Duplicate Question......http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382994/how-to-check-if-any-javascript-event-listeners-handlers-attached-to-an-element-d

Answer (score 6):

This should get you a list of events:

```
jQuery(theElement).data('events');
```

Answer (score 6):

You could try this:

```
$("element").data("events");
```

Comment: Ok I put this in the console $("#viewSaleSheet").data("events") which returned an object which held a click inside of it, but there are no click events attached to this link.  Why is it doing this??

Comment: @Tanya is `#viewSaleSheet` an anchor tag?

Comment: This is what it is:

<a href="#" id="viewSaleSheet">View </a>

Comment: @Tanya since you have a `href` , the console is considering it as onclick event,remove that href and now try `$("#viewSaleSheet").data("events")`. you will not see any events binded.

Answer (score 2):

I use the following, tested in IE, FF and Chrome:

```
if(typeof document.getElementById("elementname").onchange === "function"){ 
    alert("has a function");
} else {
    alert("no function");
}
```