# Method to determine javascript functions calls made in a browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

In a browser you can determine what files are loaded when a website loads and you can even view the timeline.

But is there any way to determine what javascript calls are being made once the script loads for a website?(in firefox or chrome or any software package)

Hope you got my question

(Because that would be useful for debugging logical javascript errors and others I suppose)

Comment: developer tools has profiling abilities

Answer (score 0):

**I use Chrome's Developer Tools for this:**

[image]

Check the click box, and then click on the element on the page you want to find the handler for. If you are using jQuery (or similar library), you may have to step through their code before you get to yours.

#### Taken from: [How do I find out what javascript function is being called by an object's onclick event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10639089/how-do-i-find-out-what-javascript-function-is-being-called-by-an-objects-onclic)

---

**Typically I just use `logging` in FireBug personally (which despite my desperate approach to avoid Chrome, is turning out to force me to adopt it with built-in developer tools).**

---