# How to track a javascript function?

Tags: javascript

I'm currently working on Chrome extenstion and I need to find a way to understand what javascript function is being called by an element.

```
<button class="yt-uix-button yt-uix-button-size-default yt-uix-button-text yt-uix-button-empty yt-uix-button-has-icon appbar-guide-toggle appbar-guide-clickable-ancestor"
        id="appbar-guide-button" type="button" onclick=";return false;"
        aria-label="Przewodnik" aria-controls="appbar-guide-menu" aria-expanded="false">
  <span class="yt-uix-button-icon-wrapper">
    <span class="yt-uix-button-icon yt-uix-button-icon-appbar-guide yt-sprite">
    </span>
  </span>
</button>
```

As you can see, the only reference to javascript function is `onclick=";return false;"` which gives me nothing. It has to be called outside.

When I click it, a javascript function is being executed, **but I need to find what function is that**. How do I do that?

Comment: What do you need to do with the function information and what have you tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10639089/how-do-i-find-out-what-javascript-function-is-being-called-by-an-objects-onclic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Edge performance tab]

You can use F12 developer tools to view all the function calls that occur in response to a mouse click.

Comment: That's it. Thanks! I'll mark this as answer in just a second